# send sms using ajax with real time total sms sended by progress bar in codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

i sending sms using ajax and waant display real-time progress bar of total sms sended by in codeigniter

i want to show sending sms count with progress bar

my controller code

```
$final_list = 'user list with data';

$recipients   = count($final_list);

$sentCount = $totalsmsSend = $totalappSend = 0;

foreach ($final_list as $user_mail_key => $user_mail_value) {
    $sentCount++;
    if (in_array("sms", $sms_mail)) {
        if ($user_mail_value['mobileno'] != "") {

            $this->smsgateway->sendSMS($user_mail_value['mobileno'], $message, $template_id, "");            

            // $response['remainingSms'] = $recipients - ($sentCount);
            $totalsmsSend ++;
        }
    }
    if (in_array("push", $sms_mail)) {
        if ($user_mail_value['app_key'] != "") {
            $this->pushnotification->send($user_mail_value['app_key'], array(
                            'title' => $message_title, 'body' => $message
                        ), "mail_sms");
                                
            // $response['remainingtoApp'] = $recipients - ($sentCount);
            $totalappSend ++;
        }
    }
                        
    // $response['status']   = 'sending';
    // $response['msg']       = 'Sending SMS ' . $sentCount . ' of ' . $recipients;
    // $response['remaining'] = ($recipients - $sentCount);
    // $response['progress']  = (($sentCount / $recipients) * 100);
    
    //header('Content-Type: application/json');
    // echo json_encode($response);

    // ob_flush();
    // flush();
    // usleep(500000); // Delay for half a second (500ms) before sending the next SMS
                        
}
                    
    $totalsend = array('sms' => $totalsmsSend, 'push' => $totalappSend);


                    
     echo json_encode(array('status' => 'success',  'api_res' => $totalsend, 'msg' => $this->lang->line('message_sent_successfully')));
```

and Jquery  ajax code

```
$("#group_form").submit(function (event) {

        event.preventDefault();
        var formData   = new FormData();
        var other_data = $(this).serializeArray();
        
        $.each(other_data, function (key, input) {
            formData.append(input.name, input.value);
        });

        var $form = $(this),
            $this = $form.find(':submit');
        
        var jqXHR = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $form.attr('action'),
            data: formData,
            dataType: "JSON",
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function () { 
                $this.button('loading'); 
                $('#smsprocess').modal({backdrop: 'static',keyboard: false,show: true});
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.status == 0) {
                    var message = "";
                    $.each(data.msg, function (index, value) {
                        message += value; 
                    });
                    errorMsg(message);
                } else{
                    $('#group_form')[0].reset();
                    successMsg(data.msg);
                }
                $('#smsprocess').modal('hide');
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                if (jqXHR.statusText == 'abort') {
                    errorMsg('Sending Process Aborted.');
                    return;
                }
            }, 
            complete: function (data) { 
                $this.button('reset');
            }
        });
        
        $('#abort').on('click', function() {
            $('#smsprocess').modal('hide');
            jqXHR.abort();
        });

    });
```

sending 1000+ SMS in bulk using AJAX and getting real-time remaining SMS to send or total SMS sent with a progress bar in CodeIgniter